# Why are the Stack Overflow job page and apply for job page sometimes mismatching?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

For example, here is [a job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/134299/senior-software-engineer-php-m-f-wayfair-gmbh?offset=17) on Stack Overflow. The title of the job is "(Senior) Software Engineer - PHP".

The main requirements are: PHP, DB/SQL skills, and front-end techs (HTML, JavaScript, and CSS).

When you click the "apply" button, you are redirected to a page where the job title says: "(Senior) iOS Developer" and first paragraph from "You have" section is:

> 4+ years of iOS development – experience with Objective-C, Swift, and/or Cocoa

These techs are nowhere mentioned on Stack Overflow, nor in text, nor in job tags.

Though here also requested PHP and SQL, but anyway, there is an important mismatch between Stack Overflow Jobs and "APPLY FOR THIS JOB" page.

Or did I understand something incorrectly?

Comment: Looks like an application that takes you off-site, as opposed to applying on Jobs itself. I'd assume this is something the company posting the job is doing, and they may not realize that the job ad is different from the application. It might be worth flagging the job posting and explaining this issue to the Stack team, so they can reach out to the company about this mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. It looks like the employer initially linked the job listing to the wrong page on their end.  It's linking to the right place now. If you come across this again in the future, please flag the job and our team will reach out to the employer.